# Center a field set with CSS

Tags: html, css, fieldset

I'm trying to center a fieldset containing the login "username" and "password" fields to the center of the page. Here is what I have:

```
fieldset{
  border: 1px solid rgb(255,232,57);
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}
```

I want the fieldset to be centered in the window, regardless of window size. Googling produced nothing helpful, such as `float: center` or `align: center` attributes.

Comment: use 'margin:auto' instead of float

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no `float: center`, only left and right. Float simply allows block level elements to line up horizontally by taking them out of their stack flow. It's similar to `display:inline-block` except it aligns them to the direction of the float.

What you want is to set the margins to auto. If you want to center align the nodes *inside* the `fieldset`, you can add `text-align:center;` to this:

```
fieldset{
  border: 1px solid rgb(255,232,57);
  width: 400px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Haha no worries man. The downvote wasn't from me. +1 to balance that out :)

Answer (score 4):

The element wrapping it likely needs text-align: center; on it, and then you need to set the margins on the fieldset;

```
fieldset{
  //other stuff
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}

form
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/CKqxQ/

Comment: Setting the text-align on the wrapping element would be extraneous if the fieldset is displayed block level with auto left and right margins.

Comment: @lthibodeaux Some older versions of IE can have troubles without it, so I normally place it in. It is extraneous though for any newer browsers.

Comment: That is not solving the problem. Only the wrapping parent is adjusted to the center. The content will not be centered to the center of the component

Answer (score 2):

just remove `float:left` and add `margin: 0 auto;` because `float:left` keeps your element to left of the parent element. (Assuming parent element width is more than 400px;) your new css would be as below.

```
fieldset{
  border: 1px solid rgb(255,232,57);
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the `fieldset` like that:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    .......fieldset here........
</div>
```

Note: This affects also the alignment of the `fieldset` text, so if you want the text inside the `fieldset` to be aligned left or right, you can use:

```
<fieldset style="text-align:left">
```

Answer (score -1):

Someone try this... actually,just use this coz it works!

```
fieldset {
  font-size:14px;    padding:5px;    width:500px;    line-height:1.8;    margin: 0 auto;    
 }
```

Comment: The line that's important is `margin: 0 auto;` which is already mentioned by both previous answer. So what value does this answer add?