# Align fieldset legend at center

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<fieldset class="Fieldset">
    <legend class="Legend" id="Legend">Add</legend>
    ...
```

CSS

```
.Fieldset
{
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.Legend
{
    border: medium none;
    left: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    color: #3C6EAC;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

In `Firefox` legend gets aligned at center. But in `Chrome` it does not.

Comment: shakhrillo's answer is better overall and is the correct way to deal with it. There is no need to add `margin-left: 40%` because `text-align` will align it for you. It's only because you have `left: 40%` in there that stops the `text-align` from working correctly.

Comment: @Ruddy, it does not centrally align the legend in Firefox.

Comment: Hmm, that's very odd. And you are correct, not sure why that is. I tend not to use Firefox anymore so that's why I missed it! In that case setting a margin is probably the next best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this `CSS`, remove `margin :auto` & `left:40%` then add `margin-left:40%`.

```css
.Fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.Legend {
  border: medium none;
  margin-left: 40%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  color: #3C6EAC;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="Fieldset">
  <legend class="Legend" id="Legend">Add</legend>
</fieldset>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QSmJb/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Simply delete `left:40%` from `.Legend` and `text-align` will do the rest.

```css
.Fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.Legend {
  border: medium none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  color: #3C6EAC;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="Fieldset">
  <legend class="Legend" id="Legend">Add</legend>
</fieldset>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QSmJb/4/)

Comment: This is a better answer (read more on my comment on the question). +1 from me.

Comment: Isn't firefox friendly. :(

Answer (score 0):

- `margin:auto;` is doing all the work
- `text-align:center;` does not do anything
- `left:40%;` interferes with `margin:auto;`

Run this example:

```css
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

legend {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #3C6EAC;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Long title long title long title long title </legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Same question with good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898072/center-a-field-set-with-css

Answer (score 0):

This post is useful. However, I managed to align the legend to the center just with text-align:center as shown below.

```
legend {
  text-align:center;
}
```

StackBlitz example for the same is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzmpzi