# Align elements in a fieldset

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a combination of labels and inputs. Currently using a `fieldset > table > tr > td` structure. I've read online that this is typically poor practice, however, I'm having a very difficult time using CSS to accomplish the look I need.

Here is a sample:

```css
td.right {
  text-align: right;
}

fieldset {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  padding-top: 0.35em;
  padding-bottom: 0.625em;
  padding-left: 0.75em;
  padding-right: 0.75em;
  border: 2px groove;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="right">Date of Call:</td>
      <td><input class="datepicker2" name="callDate"></td>
      <td class="right">Caller code Number:</td>
      <td><input class="CodeMaker" name="callerCodeNum"></td>
      <td class="right">What is the jurisdiction?</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="jurisdiction"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="right">Date of Offense:</td>
      <td><input class="datepicker2" name="crimeDate"></td>
      <td class="right">Time of Offense:</td>
      <td><input class="timePicker?" name="crimeTime"></td>
      <td class="right">Number:</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

This renders nicely with the table formatting (3 label/input combinations for the first row, and 3 label/input combinations for the second row). There are basically 3 columns.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for providing your existing HTML, but could you please provide your existing CSS as well; we can't reproduce your problem without it. Please update your question so that it shows your **existing CSS**, along with your **desired outcome**, thus forming a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: The only styling I have is for the td elements and fieldset elements:
td.right{
 text-align: right;
}
fieldset {
 display: block;
 margin-left: 2px;
 margin-right: 2px;
 padding-top: 0.35em;
 padding-bottom: 0.625em;
 padding-left: 0.75em;
 padding-right: 0.75em;
 border: 2px groove;
}

Comment: BTW, thank you for your prompt response. I have it set up to notify (by email) of responses, however I don't seem to have receive a notification. The above "Run code snippet" seems to be rendering fairly closely to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I didn't add anything special to the above snippet; I simply added the CSS you wrote as a comment to your existing HTML. That should be the display you **already have**. Please edit your question to clearly specify your **desired outcome**, and how the above snippet **differs** from the desired outcome -- otherwise you don't have a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replicate a table using CSS with the `display` property and values `table` `table-row` `table-cell` etc.

There are a number of reasons why it is bad practice to use tables for your layout. A quick search will return dozens of articles on this issue.

I see the main reasons as: Table layouts are not semantic; if you are not displaying tabular data, don't use a table. Table layouts are not accessible - users using a screen reader will not be happy. Once you get used to CSS to provide the styling to your layout you will find it much easier to maintain.

```css
fieldset {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  padding-top: 0.35em;
  padding-bottom: 0.625em;
  padding-left: 0.75em;
  padding-right: 0.75em;
  border: 2px groove;
}

.table {
  display: table;
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.td {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.td.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td right">Date of Call:</div>
    <div class="td"><input class="datepicker2" name="callDate"></div>
    <div class="td right">Caller code Number:</div>
    <div class="td"><input class="CodeMaker" name="callerCodeNum"></div>
    <div class="td right">What is the jurisdiction?</div>
    <div class="td"><input type="text" name="jurisdiction"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td right">Date of Offense:</div>
    <div class="td"><input class="datepicker2" name="crimeDate"></div>
    <div class="td right">Time of Offense:</div>
    <div class="td"><input class="timePicker?" name="crimeTime"></div>
    <div class="td right">Number:</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td right">Date of Call:</div>
    <div class="td"><textarea rows="5" cols="15"></textarea></div>
    <div class="td right">Caller code Number:</div>
    <div class="td"><textarea rows="5" cols="15"></textarea></div>
    <div class="td right">What is the jurisdiction?</div>
    <div class="td"><textarea rows="5" cols="15"></textarea></div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a heap itodd!!

Comment: Okay, so I ran into a problem. By implementing the change you provided, the elements are now floating left. I tried using css to keep the elements centered (per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898072/center-a-field-set-with-css) (using margin: 0 auto;) however it still floats left. I commented out the margin-left and margin-right settings in the original css but still no luck. Thoughts?

Comment: Okay, so by changing <fieldset class="table"> to simply <fieldset> the alignment issue resolved.

Comment: Okay, so now I'm running into an issue. I'm trying to create three textboxes in a row, but the text that should be adjacent (to the left) to the text boxes is being pushed down so that it is to the left (but below) the text boxes.

Comment: @StackBoy if you feel this answer is helpful and answers your question feel free to upvote and accept the answer. To fix your alignment issue with `textarea` you need to use `vertical-align: top;`. Check out the updated code in my answer